# How to add a input group addon into a bootstrap 3 form

Tags: html, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm trying to add a input-group-addon onto the right of an input-group.  It works if it's not in a from, but I cant get it to work in a from. Any ideas?

```
<form class="form-signin">


        <h1 class="form-signin-heading" align="center">Owner Gateway</h1>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>


        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox">Show</span>
        </div>

      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="new-btn" type="submit">Stay Logged in</button>
    </div>
    </div class="container">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox">Show</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      </form>
```

Comment: I put that in [bootply](http://bootply.com/104732) Is that what you want? or what's the issue?

Comment: cheers for the help, but i've managed to sort it. adding margin to an input box affects the input-group-addon differently. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to sort it. adding margin to an input box affects the input-group-addon differently